# Regex captures more than intended

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have written this simple Regex to capture the six characters *after* "WKN ", but I must be doing something wrong because it returns "WKN" also.

```
search_reply = "WKN A12BHF, IS3R"

wkn = re.search("WKN\s(.{6})", search_reply.text)

>>> "WKN A12BHF"
```

For this example, I would like to keep only `"A12BHF"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookbehind here:

```
>>> re.search(r"(?<=WKN\s).{6}", search_reply).group()
'A12BHF'
```

`(?<=WKN\s)` asserts that 6 digit text is preceded by `WKN` and a space.

Answer (score 2):

```
wkn = re.search("WKN\s(.{6})", search_reply.text).group(1)
```

Should do it.Your regex is correct.What you want is being captured in a `group` `()`

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

search_reply = "WKN A12BHF, IS3R"

wkn = re.search("(WKN\s)(.{6})", search_reply)

print(wkn.group(2))
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

A common regex for finding WKN, also without the "WKN" at the beginning:

```
re.search("(?<!\S)[A-Z0-9]{6}(?!\S)", text)
```